# What are the urls required to unblock through firewall in corporate network for accessing for Google Translate API (Advanced Version)?

Tags: google-translator-toolkit

**What are the urls required to unblock through firewall in corporate network for accessing for Google Translate API (Advanced Version)?**

**Right now unblocked are:**
*.googleapis.com and accounts.google.com

**But still I get below error:**
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {​​​​​​​​"created":"@1612337108.132000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":4090,"referenced_errors":[{​​​​​​​​"created":"@1612337108.132000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"T:\src\github\grpc\workspace_csharp_ext_windows_x64\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":394,"grpc_status":14}​​​​​​​​]}​​​​​​​​") at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg) at Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx) at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation) at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request) at Google.Cloud.Translate.V3.TranslationService.TranslationServiceClient.TranslateText(TranslateTextRequest request, CallOptions options) at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings) at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings) at ABG.Foundation.LanguageTranslator.GoogleTranslator.TranslateData(String sourceLanguage, String targetLanguage, List`1 content) in D:\a\1\s\src\Foundation\LanguageTranslator\code\GoogleTranslator\GoogleTranslator.cs:line 106 at ABG.Foundation.LanguageTranslator.GoogleTranslator.TranslateData(List`1 items, String sourceLanguage, String targetLanguage) in ...

**NOTE: Same code and setup works fine outside the corporate network.**

Comment: can you format it to readable form?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same issue